# Home Router (DD-WRT) and using DMASQ for a host via dynamically assigned via DHCP

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

I have a home Home Router (DD-WRT) and I want to be able to look up machines via hostname.
However, I would like to do this with machines where the IP Address id dynamically given via DHCP.   Example hosts names from my network:

```
Machine                    Hostname IP address   Method
----------------------     -------- ----------   -----------
Router                             192.168.1.1
File Server                abcd    192.168.1.2   (Static)
HTPC                       htpc    192.168.1.x   (Dynamic)
Windows Gaming Machine     bear    192.168.1.x   (Dynamic)
```

I have 1 machines which have static IP addresses, and I am able to connect to this machine via the hostname because I have configured the hostname in the DNSMasq section of my DD-WRT

**DD-WRT Panel -> Services Tab -> Services Sub tab -> DNSMasq section**

> address=/abcd/192.168.1.123

I want to be able to access HTPC via the htpc hostname from within my network, but i don't want to put it in the DNSMasq configuration section because it's not always gauranteed the same IP address.   Is there a setting to tell DD-WRT to dynamically configure DNSMasq for hosts who don't have static IP's (instead have DHCP)??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DD-WRT, you can configure DHCP to give a particular host (given a specific MAC address) a static hostname and IP address. This is called *static DHCP lease*.

If you take this approach, you'll get some of the benefits of both: your HTPC IP/hostname is managed by DHCP, but you'll always know what it is. dnsmasq in DD-WRT will also make use of this information so you can look up the machine by hostname.

Here are instructions on how to set this up:

- http://www.dd-wrt.ca/wiki/index.php/Static_DHCP
- http://www.howtogeek.com/69612/how-to-set-up-static-dhcp-on-your-dd-wrt-router/

Also, to avoid conflicts with other DHCP clients, you should change DHCP server's IP range to control which IP addresses are usable for dynamic use. In your case...

```
Machine                    Hostname IP address   Method
----------------------     -------- ----------   -----------
Router                             192.168.1.1
File Server                abcd    192.168.1.2   (Static)
HTPC                       htpc    192.168.1.5   (Static DHCP assignment)
Windows Gaming Machine     bear    192.168.1.nn  (Dynamic DHCP assignment)
```

... you want DHCP to only issue IPs where `nn` is some value greater than 5.